# Range.Find.Execute (C#) ignores Time format

Tags: c#, string, ms-word, office-interop

## Update: A solution was found!

Instead of using a field, I just replaced that with normal text and the time format is not enforced when the text is replaced with my dynamic string.  Hope this helps!

---

I'm having a problem with updating a `Microsoft Word` template with values coming from my standalone C# Windows Application.

### Problem:

For Time inputs I allow the user to choose whether they would like their times in 12-hour format with am/pm or 24-hour format.  I have things working great application-side.  But when I call `Range.Find.Execute`, and I have 24-hour format selected, the final word document and pdf do not have the times formatted that way.  The fields in the template get replaced, but they are in 12-hour format no matter what string I pass into `Range.Find.Execute`.

### What I've tried:

Here is the code that I've tried this with:

```
private void FindAndReplace(Application wordApp,
                            object findText,
                            object replaceWithText)
{
    object matchCase = true;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundsLike = false;
    object nmatchAllWordForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiacritics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;

    foreach (Range range in wordApp.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges)
    {
        Range range2 = range;
        while (range2 != null)
        {
            range2.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards,
                ref matchSoundsLike, ref nmatchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format,
                ref replaceWithText, ref replace, ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                ref matchControl);

            range2 = range2.NextStoryRange;
        }
    }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> sEntry in qirSummaryData)
{
    FindAndReplace(_mWordApp, sEntry.Key, sEntry.Value);
}
```

When `replaceWithText` is the string `"13:48"` for instance, the `Microsoft Word` document or pdf will have a `1:48 pm` instead.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?  I'm assuming that `Microsoft Word` has its own Time formatting applied after the fact, but I can't find how to programmatically set this formatting, let alone find it in `Microsoft Word` itself.

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Show some of the calling code.  Are you passing in a DateTime object, or a string?

Comment: Are the times mostly generated from fields (one of your remarks suggests that) and if so, are you sure the fields themselves are being replaced, and not just their results? The results will be regenerated when you print/PDF and they will depend on a number of settings plus any date time format specified in the field code. You can try switching off field update at print time but it may not be enough to prevent regeneration (e.g. In headers/footers at least)

Comment: The `WinForms` controls are `DevExpress` `TimeEdit`s but when it comes time to replace the fields in the `Microsoft Word` document, I'm passing in a string.  For example, please see the calling code in my updated question